# How to restrict maximum length for html editor field in extjs 4

Tags: javascript, extjs, textarea

I am trying to restrict my html editor field to maximum 1000 character , but there is no config option in htmleditor field. And also want to make htmleditor field as mandatory field, for that also no config is available.

Is it possible to restrict the htmleditor , and can it be a mandatory field?

If it is than please help me in this, please share some code if possible so that i can understand how to do it.

I tried `enforceMaxLength: true`,`maxLength: 1000,` both property is working fine when user types the content, but user when copy paste the content then is showing more than the count.

Comment: Think about this: If maxLength enforcement would be possible, how many characters would an image, bold text, colored text... take?

Comment: And please note: Since HTML requires closing tags (not always, but sometimes), cutting HTML to the required max length is not such a trival task.

Comment: You probably mean maximum 1000 characters of html text with markup? Please clarify the question.

Comment: @PeterIvan yes, html markup will come when the content copy paste from any website